# Access number enum passing string

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I'm trying to access `id` based on animal `name`:

```
enum Animals {
  Cat = 1,
  Dog,  // 2
}

const name: string = "Cat";

const id: number = Animals[name] // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
```

Referred from https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/enums.html#enums-and-strings

```
enum Tristate {
  False,
  True,
  Unknown
}

console.log(Tristate["False"]); // 0
```

Question - How to get `1` associated with `Cat`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Animals%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Cat%20%3D%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20Dog%2C%20%20%2F%2F%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20n%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22Cat%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20d%3A%20number%20%3D%20Animals%5Bn%5D%3B

Comment: I still don't understand, even changing type of  `d` to `string` ts doesn't alarm when `Cat` has type `number` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Animals%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Cat%20%3D%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20Dog%2C%20%20%2F%2F%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20n%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22Cat%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20d%3A%20string%20%3D%20Animals%5Bn%5D%3B

Comment: Change `const name: string = "Cat";` to 
`const name = "Cat";`

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a variable (e.g., `name`) to address the value for an enum, if you define the type as `string`, it thinks it could contain any value, even values that do not exist in the enum. So the output becomes `any`.

To avoid this issue, you can either directly call the enum (`Animals['Cat']`) or you can limit the values of your variable to the enum values as follows:

```
const name: 'Cat' | 'Dog' = 'Cat';
const id: number = Animals[name]; // 1
```

Comment: You're correct but the most straightforward fix is to just remove the type annotation and let the compiler infer the type: `const name = "Cat";` will infer name to be of type `"Cat"`.

Comment: Correct, but in case the input to the variable is coming from another source during runtime, we can ensure the type this way.

Comment: Actually in that case, the type would be wrong. Type annotations have no runtime impact whatsoever.

Comment: I was thinking about a case where a function based on some input has a return of `'Cat' | 'Dog'`. In this case, this type annotation enforces the `Animals` enum type. I agree that potentially any value can be passed during the runtime, but an intermediary function with this defined type might help eliminate the issue. Thoughts?

Comment: yeah... in such a case you should write the type based on the possible set of runtime values, e.g. `string`. By annotating with the type that is more specific than you can guarantee, you're actually doing the exact opposite of what you're trying to achieve. A more specific type in such a case leads to a false sense of security.

Comment: I suggest defining an intermediate type guard function that checks the value. `function inEnum(k: string): k is keyof Animals {return Object.keys(Animals).includes(k);}`. This will do the right thing and pushes the types out so they are the result of validated values

Comment: @AluanHaddad I agree, what you suggested should be safe to future changes in the enum.